# How can I solve large size Least norm-2 Problem?

Tags: least-squares

As shown in the title, the least norm-2 problem can be formulated as
$$\min_{x}{\|Ax-b\|_2^2}$$
where $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n},b\in\mathbb R^m$ are parameters with $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$ and $x\in\mathbb R^n$ is variable.

As the above problem equals to 
$$A^TAx=A^Tb$$

the closed form solution is
$$x^*=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$

As the size of $A^TA$ is $n\times n$, reaching $(A^TA)^{-1}$ becomes quite challenging if $n$ is a quite large number. So my question is is there any methods that can improve the computation efficiency with quite large $n$?

Comment: In general, equations of the form $Mx = y$ may be solved with less computation than is required to find $M^{-1}$.  For example: with matlab, one can write `x = M\y`.

Comment: Not needing to calculate or store $M^{-1}$ can easily be the difference being able to solve a problem and not.

Answer (score 4):

For problems in which the $A$ matrix is large and sparse, iterative methods such as [LSQR](https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/lsqr/) are commonly used.  An effective preconditioner can be very important to the performance of these iterative methods.

Comment: What is "LSQR", for the uninitiated?

Comment: I've added a link to the answer.  LSQR is an iterative algorithm for linear least squares problems that is widely used.

Comment: It really bothers me that however deep I dig, nobody clarifies the acronym LSQR.  Clearly it's least squares `____  ____`, or I guess they might mean $QR$ as in the $QR$ decomposition.  Upon further inspection: yes, it's least-squares "QR", as in the decomposition.

Comment: The paper in which LSQR was introduced doesn't define it as an acronym.  It's simply a name.

Comment: and to me, that just seems insane.  In any case, I've decoded the would-be acronym to my satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

Factorization methods are popular and there exist very many. For example QR-factorization.

Another family of methods which are often used are the [Krylov subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace) methods. Maybe most well known is the [Conjugate Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method). They utilize the krylov subspaces

$$\{v,Av,A^2v,\cdots,A^kv\}$$

Which can be used to iterative approximate solutions using matrix-vector multiplication which is often very cheap and/or fast for sparse matrixes (compared to matrix inversion).

Answer (score 1):

One of the wost important keyword here is "pseudo-inverse".

The (Moore Penrose) pseudo-inverse can be plainly defined as $A^+:=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$.

$x^*=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb \iff x^*=A^+b$,

which, if you work with Matlab, uses the following syntax: $x=pinv(A)*b$

It is not at all a subterfuge using a new word hiding old calculations.

A numerical computer software like Matlab doesn't obtain the pseudo-inverse through a computation of the inverse of $A^TA$, often very ill-conditionned thus too prone to huge numerical errors. Instead, it uses SVD (and, as I have understood, other "under the hood" tricks), bypassing the pitfalls of the direct method.

Have a look at (https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoeldsee263/Additional4-ls_ln_matlab.pdf) which considers the two cases $m>n$ and $m<n$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

A brief comparison of solution methods is provided here: [Comparing LU or QR decompositions for solving least squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040363/comparing-lu-or-qr-decompositions-for-solving-least-squares/2181129#2181129)
which discusses flop counts and stability.